# Reading Column Specific Data in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, ifstream, getline

I have a data file like this;

```
 -2.27454 -5.24555  1.74353  6.85324
 -2.24454 -3.22450  2.66345  5.41232
 -2.22400 -3.15505  3.73432  4.73253
  2.19454 -3.16660  5.01444  5.74353
  2.24454 -3.15440  6.04344  6.70345
  2.27454 -3.12530  7.04543  5.74354
```

I am reading it line by line like this;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string all_lines[999];
    string column_1[999];
    string column_2[999];
    string column_3[999];
    string column_4[999];
    int i = 0;
    ifstream file("data.txt");
    while(getline(file, all_lines[i])){
        cout << all_lines[i];
        cout << "\n";
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I split those lines to respective columns and assign them to column_1, column_2, column_3 and column_4. Not like vector!!
It should be like this;

```
column_1[0] = -2.27454
column_2[0] = -5.24555
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you really want them as strings? Looks like you could conveniently read them in as floats. Unreliable input syntax (like anything typed in by a human) would be a very good reason to at least read them in as strings initially.

Comment: Are you aware of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream ? If yes, please explain why they do not seem an option for you?

Comment: @Yunnosch I changed the data file normally the numbers present in Scientific notation. First I need to read them as string then convert it to float. Also I need to perform some numerical operations on columns. That is why I wanted to read file once get rid of it and do every operation with arrays.